# Remove(unselect) selected items from list box using javascript

Tags: javascript, listbox

I tried this,

`document.getElementById('<% = ListBox1.ClientID %>').options.length = 0;` what this does is clear my items of my listbox.. I simply want to unselect the selected items.. Any suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
ListBox1.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearSelected(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("ddBusinessCategory").selectedOptions;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.